# Is it possible to have postgres9.6 and postgis 2.3 on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I want to upgrade/install postgres9.6 and postgis2.3 on trusty but I cannot find a way...

Has someone succeed on that?

Ps. this repo

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'`

leads to [broken packages issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217727/broken-packages-and-unmet-dependency-installation-qgis-postgresql-and-postgis-u)

Comment: You will probably have to build from source, as the packaged versions tend to be a little bit behind, even on Ubuntu.

Comment: @JohnBarça, Hello. I tried in different ways but I can have psql 9.6 and postgis 2.3 for xenial not  trusty... maybe there is not available : I saw the repo is empty for trusty

Comment: As I said, you need to build from source, if you want the latest. The packaged versions are often behind, which is understandable. Once you have the build tools set up (build essential), it's not really that painful, though you will probably need to build GEOS, proj4 and gdal, as well as Postgres and Postgis.

Comment: Hi @JohnBarça, I don't know what it means 'build from source'... I am making some research about that..Maybe Do I need to follow these step here? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/installation.html