# Different output of gdalinfo --version and gdal-config in Xenial

Tags: qgis, gdal, postgresql, r

I have Ubuntu 16.04 with postgresql 9.6 postgis 2.3 QGIS 2.18 installed.

I am trying to install `mapview` (R library) with no success because of sf defencency.

I had this output:

```
    configure: GDAL: 1.11.3
checking GDAL version >= 2.0.0... no
configure: error: sf is not compatible with GDAL versions below 2.0.0
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/sf’
```

and this is what happened on the terminal:

```
$gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25
$ gdal-config --version
1.11.3
```

I am wondering the following questions:

Which is the difference between `gdalinfo` and `gdal-config` ?

Why does R say me that I have a `GDAL` version less than `2.0.0` even if output of `gdalinfo --version` is `GDAL 2.1.0`?

How can I upgrade Gdal-config to one >= 2.0.0?

If I upgrade, will I have problem with postgresql, postgis Qgis or some other python module that use `GDAL`?

Answer (score 2):

gdal-config is part of the package `libgdal-dev`, while gdalinfo is part of `gdal-bin`.

You can run `apt-cache policy <packagename>` to see what you have installed, and what is available for you.

Surely both packages should be from the same GDAL release to get things running without errors.

GDAL version 1.11.3 is in the main ubuntu repo, ubuntugis unstable PPA has 2.1.3, while ubuntugis (stable) has 2.1.0 for Xenial.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Really useful! 
@AndreJ, this is the output of  `apt-cache policy libgdal-dev`
`libgdal-dev:
  Installed: 1.11.3+dfsg-3build2
  Candidate: 1.11.3+dfsg-3build2
  Version table:
 *** 1.11.3+dfsg-3build2 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

It seems I cannot upload to version 2.1.0 without any conflict..right?

Comment: Please run the same on gdal-bin to see where you got that in version 2.1.0 from.

Comment: Hi @AndreJ

this is the output: 

`gdal-bin:
  Installed: 2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2
  Candidate: 2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.11.3+dfsg-3build2 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages`

Comment: Seems you have removed a ubuntugis ppa after installing. If R needs that, you have to add the ppa back to your sources and update. Where did you get postgis from? Ubuntugis unstable has postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.3.

Comment: I didn't use PPA because of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217727/broken-packages-and-unmet-dependency-installation-qgis-postgresql-and-postgis-u. You helped me, remember?
output `apt-get policy postgis`:

`postgis:
  Installed: 2.3.2+dfsg-1~exp2.pgdg16.04+1
  Candidate: 2.3.2+dfsg-1~exp2.pgdg16.04+1
  Version table:
 *** 2.3.2+dfsg-1~exp2.pgdg16.04+1 500
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.2.1+dfsg-2 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages`

Comment: I did not remember ;-)- But now you are stucked with R expecting GDAL 2. Perhaps you should set up a virtual box to see if you can upgrade to GDAL 2 and dependent packages for postgis **and** R with ubuntugis unstable. If you fail, you still have your current database running safely.