# Bonn 3.2.2 to buggy need to install older version of QGIS

Tags: qgis, installation

I am having a lot of issues with Bonn 3.2.2 QGIS and would like to uninstall this version and install an older version that is more stable.

1. What seems to be a stable version of version 3?
2. What is the best way to do so on Linux?

Answer (score 3):

The most stable version is the long term release (LTR) which is at 2.18.24.  The 3.2 series is at 3.2.3.

Comment: Thank you ,  do happen to know the best way to uninstall and reinstall 2.18

Comment: same way you installed it

Comment: I know how to install the latest version or update the version but how do you install  a specific version such as 2.18  (Long Term Release Repository)

Comment: There's a link to download the long term release on the [QGIS download page](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html).

Comment: A link to what, I am new to Linux and am having a hard time figuring this install process?  I know where the download page is but it is all foreign to me and not sure what my next step is to install it.  All help appreciated!

Comment: afte this:sudo apt-get install qgis this is the error i get The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis : Depends: python-qgis (= 1:2.18.24+28bionic) but 1:3.2.3+28bionic is to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-plugin-grass but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-provider-grass but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: You have to install qgis and python-qgis together. Make sure to have purged the QGIS 3 version before re-installing. Try `apt-cache policy qgis` to see what is available for you. Alternatively, use aptitude instead of apt.

Comment: this is what i get now:zaccollins@pop-os:~$ apt-cache policy qgis
qgis:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.18.24+28bionic
  Version table:
     1:3.2.3+28bionic -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:2.18.24+28bionic 500
        500 https://qgis.org/debian-ltr bionic/main amd64 Packages
     2.18.20+dfsg-1~bionic1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     2.18.17+dfsg-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: this is how i did it:The following worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 and QGIS 2.18:

sudo apt remove *qgis*
sudo apt purge *qgis*
Then:

sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis python-qgis

Answer (score 2):

*Ihis is how I did it:*

The following worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 and QGIS 2.18:

sudo apt remove qgis

sudo apt purge qgis

**Then:** 
sudo apt update

sudo apt install qgis python-qgis

this was found here [Broken packages and unmet dependency installation QGIS, PostgreSQL and postgis Ubuntu 14.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217727/broken-packages-and-unmet-dependency-installation-qgis-postgresql-and-postgis-u) and posted by Karlo Guidoni Martins

Thnk you for all that offered help.